# Figuring out the money related tags

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

We currently have the tags [salary](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salary) [money](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) [payment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/payment) [pay](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pay) [benefits](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/benefits) [expenses](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expenses) and [raise](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raise).

That's really too many tags, and many are being used interchangably. I initially intended "salary" to refer to issues specific to salaried payments, as opposed to hourly payments, but that just hasn't happened.

I think all "money I am paid for doing my job" questions should be bundled into one tag, IMO [payment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/payment) is best for that. All non-payment issues about giving an *employee* money, as in *benefits*, should be tagged [benefits](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/benefits). Questions dealing with spending company money should be tagged [expenses](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expenses). Asking about increased pay (not benefits) should be [raise](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raise) I don't really see any useful, common distinction beyond that.

Better ideas? Is this okay? What should we do here?

---

I killed [money](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) by retagging those questions manually, it's too vague to make a synonym. I synonymized [pay](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pay) and [payment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/payment) to [salary](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salary) for now, that seems to be the consensus. [raise](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raise) [benefits](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/benefits) and [expenses](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expenses) are all fine by me, but **they need tag wikis/excerpts** to define their proper use.

Comment: Interesting.  I submitted a potential wiki description for *money* only yesterday, because of precisely this issue.  Also mentioned it in a question on meta.stackoverflow - is this in response to either of those?

Comment: @itsbruce not directly, though I did happen to notice "money" and remembered an earlier issue of salary vs pay/payment.

Answer (score 5):

Use [salary](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salary) to indicate questions related to "money I'm being paid." [payment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/payment) might be a "most correct" term but I disagree on using it because it is not the most straightforward to users unfamiliar with this site.

Probably 99% of users coming to this site will instinctively think to search or tag questions with [salary](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salary) vs [payment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/payment), as well as what almost all people will search via google.

I also think [raise](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raise) is a valid tag as it pertains to another specific set of things people will be looking to try to do.

Leave [benefits](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/benefits) as that is also a specific and unique thing. Get rid of [money](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money), [pay](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pay), and [payment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/payment).

Comment: I'm okay with this. I forgot to mention raise;  it's yet another money tag but like you say it's a distinct problem. Current pay, payment and salary are not distinct.

Answer (score 3):

On this one, I'm thinking a basic strategy is to go with what's intuitive.  Current usage says:

[salary](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salary) - 41 questions

[money](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) - 3 - 1 about salary, 2 about other types of money that isn't payment for work

[pay](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pay) - 6 - none overlap with salary, but look like they could be fused with salary

[payment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/payment) - 5 - does overlap with pay - also refers in usage to payment for work

[benefits](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/benefits) - 2 - neither of which relate to negotiation, or of compensation

[expenses](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expenses) - 3 - seems mostly about transfer of money for conditions that are not
classic salary or payment - like travel costs or other "expense account" type issues

[raise](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raise) - 3 - cases of increasing payment for work within an existing job.

Give the love of [salary](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salary) as a tag, I'd say eliminate [money](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) (fuse it into salary or expenses), [pay](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pay) (fuse into salary), [payment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/payment) (fuse into salary).  Keep [benefts](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/benefts) - non-monetary compensation for work, [expenses](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expenses) - money provided for incidental costs relating to or required by work, and [raise](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raise) - increases in salary within an existing job.

Answer (score 0):

It seems [salary](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salary) should be the tag for salary/wages, and [pay](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pay) should be a synonym. While this may be less intuitive for questions about hourly pay, I think it's a good fit.

We should keep [benefits](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/benefits) to cover all non-monetary compensation to an employee.

It would be useful to keep [expense](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expense) around, covering questions about compy expenses or reimbursement by an employer for personally-paid expenses (such as parking or public transportation).

We should get rid of [money](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money). It's a bit broad, and could cover salary (covered by [salary](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salary)), expenses (covered by [expenses](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expenses)), or investment/financing (off-topic). Similarly, [payment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/payment) strikes me as "a payment" more so than "payment for services of an employee", and I suggest we get rid of it (or at least synonymize it with [salary](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salary)).

Lastly, [raise](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raise) isn't *really* covered by [salary](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salary), since it is also tied to promotions, performance, and changes in responsibility. However, I see no compelling reason why we can't broaden [salary](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salary) enough to include it other than potentially having a tag about negotiating (hiring, promotions, raises, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest synonymizing a few of these

Compensation => salary pay and raise payment expenses benefits

Lets eliminate and ban the Money tag it does not belong here.