# Question about two tags

Tags: discussion

So we have both the "Salary" and "Salaried-pay" tags.

Salary: Monetary compensation for work performed.

Salaried-pay: A form of payment where you receive a fixed compensation regardless of the number of hours you work. This is different than receiving compensation specifically for the hours you work.

I am of the mind that the "salary" tag should be removed, and its synonyms ("pay" and "payment") promoted instead. "Salary" technically refers to payment upon reaching a fixed interval, contrasting piece wages which are paid for time spent.  Thus, the tag entry for "Salary" doesn't really make any sense, and is overall useless as any question referring to a "Salary" would be better covered with "Salaried-pay".  Thoughts?

edit: I just noticed [This question](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/492/figuring-out-the-money-related-tags?rq=1) in the sidebar (it didn't show up as I was typing this question up)  Does it change anything?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are referring to [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10965/can-a-salaried-employee-have-their-pay-docked-by-the-hour) - I actually believe I created that tag while editing it.

The reason I did this is because right now "salary" is used for mostly anything money related on this site. Most questions tagged [salary](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salary) are not necessarily specific to [salaried-pay](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salaried-pay).

That question is **very specific** to someone paid with a defined salary and not hourly (or contract). The current tag for [salary](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salary) does not really do a good job in these cases.

---

That being said I am not 100% convinced having a tag [salary](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salary) and [salaried-pay](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salaried-pay) is ideal. But I think it is important to make a distinction between the two, or, at least, rethink how "salary" is currently being used.

Comment: Yes, that is the question that brought this to my attention.  In the case of this question, yes both "salary" and "salaried-pay" might make sense (though only the latter is NEEDED, the former contributes nothing really).  is this just a situation where we have to accept that a tag is being used incorrectly, and has become so pervasive that it's impossible to correct at this point?

Comment: I wonder how many people actually know the difference?

Comment: @jmort253 I suspect most people know the difference but whether people use that on this site? Probably not to that questino...